# Error with Groovy AST transformations when cleaning project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm trying to work through groovy's [Implementing Local AST Transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Local+AST+Transformations) tutorial, but whenever I clean my project I get this error in each file that has the @WithLogging annotation in it:

> Groovy:Could not find class for Transformation Processor AC.LoggingASTTransformation declared by AC.WithLogging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a package named "AC" that contains both "WithLogging.groovy" and "LoggingASTTransformation.groovy" classes?  Does it also contain any classes that implement the "WithLogging" interface?

If so, I'd suggest you move the class(es) that use your annotation to a location outside of the annotation defining package (the default will suffice, for diagnostic purposes) - Order of compilation matters with transformations. See [this post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Help-With-First-AST-td3286907.html) on the groovy users mailing list for more on that.

Also try changing the annotation from @WithLogging to @AC.WithLogging.

As far as cleaning with Eclipse is concerned, I had a similar issue and found that I had to make a trivial modification after a clean to any file that contained my annotation. IE, add a space somewhere. Then save the file.  This should rebuild everything properly.

Comment: I put the WithLogging annotation and the LoggingASTTransformation into a separate project referenced by the project that uses the WithLogging annotation. I am now getting this error: `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:Not an ASTTransformation: kyle.ast.LoggingASTTransformation declared by kyle.ast.WithLogging`

Comment: I clarified my wording a bit. Separate projects should work, but it complicates matters. AST transformations are a bit of a black art. I happened to be working on one this morning.. It's mostly just trial and error - Though using the AST Viewer in GroovyConsole helps considerably.. If you're still having problems, I can post some of my source (It's for automatic method timing - Quite similar to logging).

Comment: If you could post some of the source that would be really helpful.

Comment: BTW, I am able to get the transformation to work if I right click on a groovy script and choose "Run as Script", however, the transformations don't work at all for my normal project.

Comment: My source would be of no use to you, then, as I seem to be in the same position. My transformations compile, and work if I employ them outside of Eclipse - But from within it seems, short of any errors, Eclipse merely ignores them. The only advice I can give you is to convert your transforms to java (Which shouldn't be difficult, with the logging example.) I've yet to try it, but I recall reading something about that as a possible "solution."